# Can't write stream to a file

Tags: c#, file-io

I'm trying to write the output stream of a process to a file. The file is created but there is no content there (0 kb).

```
var ffmpeg = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/FFMpeg/ffmpeg.exe");
var outputDir = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/converted.mp4");
var inputArgs = "-i http://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/file_example_AVI_1280_1_5MG.avi";
var outputArgs = "-c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 26 -ac 2 -c:a aac -strict -2 -b:a 128k -f mp4 -";

var process = new Process
{
        StartInfo =
        {
            FileName = ffmpeg,
            Arguments = $"{inputArgs} {outputArgs}",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        }
 };

 process.Start();
 System.IO.Stream outputStream = process.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
 process.WaitForExit();
 if (process.HasExited)
 {
         using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(outputDir))
         {
               outputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
         }
 }
```

Comment: I think you have to read from the stream before the process exits.

Comment: Its a video converting process, so until the process ends the converted output is not completely available.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. CopyTo should block until the end of the stream is reached and everything is copied. So I would move WaitForExit() to the end and remove if(HasExited).

Comment: Tried it not working.

Comment: Did you try to use an absolute path instead of MapPath? Do other commands like "type ...\file.txt" work?